# Error crystal report runtime in windows server 2016

Tags: iis, crystal-reports, runtime, iis-10

I have developed an application on asp.net tested on Windows 10 iis and it works correctly.

Now the problem that I present is when I upload it in Windows Server 2016 iis this does not work, this type of messages appears when entering the parameters required by the report.

[image]

Both in windows 10 (in Spanish) and in windows server 2016 (in English) I have the following settings:

32-bit Crystal Runtime Version 13.0.25 Website running in application pool with 32-bit application enablement

Comment: Could you please convert the error message to English?

Comment: May you show a print screen of the formula named "fec2" of you RPT file?

Comment: This is the message: Formula error

the remaining text does not seem part of the formula

Comment: With respect to the fec2 in rpt file the strange is that in a pc with spanish language work correctly but to the pass to the server (That is in english) not work